# obfuscate id in Rails with begin range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm trying to obfuscate the ids in several models.

I accomplish this using the solution proposed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id/issues/51#issuecomment-196022028) and is working fine (I don't want to use a `gem` due the future compatibility problems).

The problem is that ids generated are small. I want them to start over the 1000000. How can accomplish this in a correct way?

The code for the model:

```
 before_create :generate_random_id

 private 

 def generate_random_id
   self.id = SecureRandom.uuid
 end
```

Comment: Here are two resources that have lots of different ways to generate different ids with different lengths: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.9/classes/ActiveSupport/SecureRandom.html and https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the id is small is because the UUID string is being converted into an integer. Use `SecureRandom.random_number(100000000000)` instead.

You need to check if the number is bigger than 1000000 and not already in the system.

```
before_create :generate_random_id

private 

def generate_random_id
  while self.id.nil? || Model.find_by_id(self.id) do
    self.id = SecureRandom.random_number(100000000000) + 1000000
  end
end
```

OR

Use uuid as the native id. Postgresql supports this natively pretty well with an extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;  
CREATE TABLE mymodel(  
   id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
   ...
);
```

Comment: That's a whole lot of work for creating a new record. Prone to race conditions too. One would be _much_ better off using uuids directly.

Comment: But if one _has_ to use integers (for whatever reason), then one would have to do something like this, yes.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Postgresql supports that well natively - http://www.starkandwayne.com/blog/uuid-primary-keys-in-postgresql/

Comment: I finally decide to use a gem and don't touch the ids in the database, I feel it a little tricky. But the second option in this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> I want them to start over the 1000000. How can accomplish this in a correct way?

So just **shift** the starting point.

```
def generate_random_id
  self.id = 1_000_000 + rand(1_000_000_000)
  # then, of course, make sure that you don't have a collision
  # (an existing record with this random id)
end
```